# Facebook Like Button does not work. Wordpress 3.2

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

My FB Like button was working fine before, and I'm not sure why it's not working anymore. I don't know if it's the Google+ code that is hindering it or if it's my upgrade to Wordpress 3. At any rate, I got rid of the G+ code and that didn't seem to fix the problem. I also looked at the Javascript console and there were no errors related to the FB like button.

If anyone could check it out, that'd be great. Here's an example of a page where it doesn't work: [dead link]
But the button works on this page:
[dead link]
Any ideas?

Comment: seems to work for me, now. Did you have a resource missing?

Comment: It works for me now too. I have a feeling the button works only when one person  likes it, and then another person who will like it will make the button count work. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this iframe

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.emmafrostfiles.com%2F2011%2F07%2Fdesigning-emma-frosts-costumes-in-x-men-first-class%2F" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="height: 62px; width: 100%" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

and search better next time

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.emmafrostfiles.com%2F2011%2F07%2Fdesigning-emma-frosts-costumes-in-x-men-first-class%2F

EDIT::

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=202840766434561&amp;href=http://www.emmafrostfiles.com/2011/07/sdcc-2011-exclusive-bishoujo-diamond-emma-frost-statue/&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=50&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=20" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 90px; height: 20px;" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

&&

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.emmafrostfiles.com%2F2011%2F07%2Fdesigning-emma-frosts-costumes-in-x-men-first-class%2F" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="height: 62px; width: 100%" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

do you see difference? Try to copy-paste second code and insert it into your site